# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1024,1280,4) (3,) (1024,1280,4) when reading png image from file

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to read a png image from file sent by http request and convert it to numpy array, I'm using the code below but the code fails in this image with error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1024,1280,4) (3,) (1024,1280,4)"

```
img = cv2.imdecode(numpy.frombuffer(request.files['file'].read(), dtype='uint8'), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

opencv version: 3.4.2, 
python: 3.7.6

the image extension is png
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's working according to broadcast specification. Check the numpy documentation for the full details, but it works like this:

1) Check if both arrays have the same number of dimensions. If they don't, extended it with 1s **from the left** (6->1,6).

2) Broadcast dimensions of 1 to the dimension in the other array (1,3*2,1->2,3)

3) If after both these steps the shapes are still different, raise an exception.

In your case, your extra dimension is on the right, so following the rules it won't work. You have to add the extra 1 dimension yourself. Both `numpy.reshape` or `numpy.expand_dims` could do it.

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to understand little bit. both arrays of what?

Comment: cv2 treats images as arrays of numbers (ints or floats depending on format). Numpy arrays specifically. So the issue is with the shape of the numpy arrays.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image

url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVBfW.png'
img = Image.open(urlopen(url))
image_array = np.array(img)

print(type(image_array))
print(image_array.shape)
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(2362, 2952, 4)
```

Comment: I'm reading the image from file sent by request post, I don't have the path of it

Comment: I don't want to have any deal with the disk, I need it to be fast as possible

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I also don't have the url of the image, I've the raw file used by (open(path, 'rb')) then I need to convert this file to numpy

Comment: @shrouk mansour i think that you don't know what you need. One time you don't wont to save data on disk and another time you dealing with raw file from some path.

Comment: I think you are not understanding me correctly, I'm receiving the image in a file format from http request so I don't have it's path I only have the image. the frontend who has sent me the image is using open(path, rb) no me actuallly.